# Read text files with c

Tags: c, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am pretty new to coding and I have some struggles with opening files. I did some basic files where the numbers where all int

Here is the example of the file:

```
20
110
1 0 1 5
5 6 7 8
```

And here is the code that I wrote to read it:

```
int* init_dados(char *name, int *n, int *iter){
FILE *f;
int *p, *q;
int i, j;

f=fopen(name, "r");
if(!f)
{
    printf("Error on the access of the file\n");
    exit(1);
}
// number of iteractions
fscanf(f, " %d", iter);
// number of vertices
fscanf(f, " %d", n);

p = malloc(sizeof(int)*(*n)*(*n));
if(!p)
{
    printf("Error on the allocation of the memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
q=p;

for(i=0; i<*n; i++)
    for(j=0; j<*n; j++)
        fscanf(f, " %d", q++);
fclose(f);
return p;
 }
```

Now I have a new file that has int and floats like this:

```
    1 2 7.83
    1 3 -5.45
    1 4 8.90
```

I want to read the text file and also print it on the screen. I thought that maybe i could do something like the last program, but I also have floats. Do I have to save them in a new vector? How would you do it? Could you please help me?

Comment: Where is the `110` vertex information? Only 8 numbers follow. However, your "new file" might need to read into a `struct` such as `struct indata { int a; int b; float f; };`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a "write my code" question with a poor example.

Comment: Please update the question. It's hard to tell what you exactly want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use %f instead of %d in fscanf, and of course you need a pointer to float variable

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like

```
int data1;
int data2;
float data3;

fscanf(f, "%d %d %e", data1, data2, data3);
```

Look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/ for a reference on fscanf.

Comment: Consider `int x; some_function(x);` `x` has not been initialized nor assigned.   What value does `some_function()` receive? `x` is not defined nor initialized and so leads to problems.  The same thing is happening here with `data1`.